# Printing function entry and exit with spaces

Tags: c, gcc

I have tried the below code to print the function entry (foo) and exit (koo). But it gives random symbols when executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char spa=' ';
void foo()
{
    printf("hai");
    spa*=2;
    printf("\n%c",spa);
}
void koo()
{
    spa/=2;
    printf("%c\n",spa);
    printf("haikoo");
}
int main()
{
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
hai
@hai
�hai
hai
hai

haikoo
haikoo
haikoo
haikoo
haikoo
```

I want output as

```
hai
  hai
    hai
      hai
        hai
        haikoo
      haikoo
    haikoo
  haikoo
haikoo
```

How can I get it? Where am I making mistake? It is for graphical representation for function call and function exit. This is just a sample program.I am using `gcc` in Linux to compile.

Comment: `spa*=2;` does not do what you (probably) think it does.

Comment: @MartinR Then how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the symbol value for the space `' '` character, not the amount of spaces. To get the output you want, you need a counter variable instead.

For example:

```
// naive solution
#include <stdio.h>

int count=0;

void print_spaces (int spaces)
{
  for(int i=0; i<spaces; i++)
  {
    printf(" ");
  }
}

void foo(void)
{
  print_spaces(count++);
  printf("hai\n");
}

void koo()
{
  print_spaces(--count);
  printf("haikoo\n");
}

int main (void)
{
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  return 0;
}
```

Better yet, don't use any global variables since that's bad practice. Use loops and leave the counter to the caller:

```
// good solution
#include <stdio.h>

int count=0;

void print_spaces (int spaces)
{
  for(int i=0; i<spaces; i++)
  {
    printf(" ");
  }
}

void foo(void)
{
  printf("hai\n");
}

void koo()
{
  printf("haikoo\n");
}

int main (void)
{
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    print_spaces(i);
    foo();
  }
  for(int i=4; i>=0; i--)
  {
    print_spaces(i);
    koo();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick, but for printing just spaces, isn't `printf` a bit of a heavy function to call?

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed. In fact the whole of stdio.h should be avoided in production code. But that's nothing beginners need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

`char spa=' ';` is character. Characters in C are an integral data type. So `spa *=2;` multiples the character value by 2. It doesn't concatenate the character to itself to form a string twice as large.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
char spa=' ';
static int i=0;
void foo()
{
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            printf("%c",spa);
        printf("hai\n");
        i+=2;
}
void koo()
{
        for(int j=0;j<i-2;j++)
            printf("%c",spa);
        printf("haikoo\n");
        i-=2;
}
int main()
{
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  koo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some discussion on how you solve the problem! Also, try to indent your code in a consistent way!